# selenium logging into tomcat manager

Tags: selenium

How do I handle the popup requesting details when going to localhost:8080/manager for tomcat?

I cannot see how tos witch to the window to type the user pass.

Ive tried using the autoauth plugin, whit no luck

I've tried

```
"driver.get("http://user:pass@localhost:8080/manager)"
```

I'm totally stuck!

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    FirefoxProfile ffProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
    ffProfile.setPreference("network.http.phishy-userpass-length", 255);
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffProfile);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

This is how I'm currently setting up my webdriver.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that webdriver supports this dialog out of the box. Anyway, to make your user:pass@site schema work, in firefox you must add parameter

```
network.http.phishy-userpass-length value: 255
```

to FF about:config. About other browsers i am not sure.

Comment: I have the following but it's not working...

     @Before
     public void setUp() throws Exception {
      FirefoxProfile ffProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
      ffProfile.setPreference("network.http.phishy-user    pass-length", 255);
      driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffProfile);
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, Time    Unit.SECONDS);
     }